# Nginx config static files cache headers

Tags: nginx

I use Nginx as front-end server for static files, in front of Apache.

1. How can I combine two similar location blocks to avoid repeating? (*location ~ .php$* and *location @apache*)
2. I need to add cache headers for static files, but the current location (commented out) doesn't work

Here's the config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name example.com

    root /home/.../public_html;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    client_max_body_size 128M;
    }

#    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff|ttf|eot)$ {
#   expires 1y;
#    }

    location / {
    try_files $uri @apache;
    }

    location @apache {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    client_max_body_size 128M;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the include directive to pull the contents for the location blocks in from a separate file.

In your example, create a file containing (called, for example "/etc/nginx/myproxy.inc")

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass_header Server;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
client_max_body_size 128M;
```

Then change your blocks like so:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/myproxy.inc
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff|ttf|eot)$ {
    try_files $uri @apache;
    expires 1y;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri @apache;
}

location @apache {
    include /etc/nginx/myproxy.inc
}
```